# Punctured complex projective space

Tags: differential-geometry, projective-space

Let $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{C}^{n}$ be the complex projective space of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, and let $B=\{\mathbf{e}_{1},\cdots,\mathbf{e}_{n+1}\}$ be a basis in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$.

I would like to understand what happens to $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{C}^{n}$ if I remove the points in it corresponding to the basis vectors in $B$.

In the case $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ I know that $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{C}^{1}\cong S^{2}$ and, from the quantum mechanical picture of $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{C}^{1}$ as the Bloch sphere, I know that the points in $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{C}^{1}$ corresponding to two basis vectors in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ are just antipodal points.
Consequently, removing these points from $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{C}^{1}$ I get a cilinder $S^{1}\times\mathbb{R}$.

Unfortunately, this visually-inspired procedure does not work in higher dimensions, and I do not know how to even start to face the problem, therefore, I appreciate any comment, suggestion or reference.

Thank You.

**EDIT**

I thought of something.

Let $\mathbf{E}_{j}$ be the rank-one projector associated to $\mathbf{e}_{j}\in B$, let $\mathbf{H}=\sum_{j}\nu_{j}\mathbf{E}_{j}$ be a self-adjoint operator on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ such that the one-parameter group of unitary operators $\mathbf{U}_{\tau}:=\exp(-\imath\tau\mathbf{H})$ on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ generated by $\mathbf{H}$ is a closed subgroup of the unitary group $U(n+1)$.
Therefore, $\mathbf{U}_{\tau}$ is an action of the circle group $U(1)\cong S^{1}$ on the complex projective space $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{C}^{n}$.
The fixed points of this action are just the points corresponding to the elements of $B$.

Let $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{C}^{n}_{*}$ denotes the complex projective space without the fixed points of the action.
Since $U(1)\cong S^{1}$ is a compact group, its action on $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{C}^{n}_{*}$ is proper.
Furthermore, it is free by construction.
This means that the orbit space $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{C}^{n}_{*}/U(1)\equiv M$ is a differential manifold, the canonical projection $\pi:\mathcal{P}\mathbb{C}^{n}_{*}\rightarrow M$ is a surjection, and $\left(\mathcal{P}\mathbb{C}^{n}_{*}\,;M\,;\pi\,;U(1)\right)$ is a $U(1)$-principal bundle.

At this point, if the bundle is trivial, we have that $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{C}^{n}_{*}\cong M\times U(1)$, however, I am not able to go further.

Comment: If possible, could you please add the type of understanding you seek? I'm guessing the main issue is that you don't have an existing picture of complex projective space from which you can remove finitely many points. (Maybe it helps to notice that removing one point from $\mathbf{CP}^{n}$ gives the total space of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{CP}^{n-1}}(1)$...?)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: roughly speaking, I would like to know if the removal of points in the complex projective space turns it into a product has it happens for $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{C}^{2}$. Obviously, I think this nice outcome is not very likely. By the way, what is the bundle You referred to?

Comment: 1. I'm pretty sure the answer is "no (the complement of $(n+1)$ points in $\mathbf{CP}^{n}$ is not a product)", but don't have a proof offhand. 2. The bundle is the "hyperplane bundle" over a projective space of one lower dimension. The geometric operation "projection away from a point $p$ onto a hyperplane not containing $p$" gives the indicated equivalence. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: If your intuition is correct, it will be so only for $n>2$, and then it will be interesting to understand why the $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{C}^{2}$ case is different

Comment: In general, the complement of $B$ in $\mathbf{CP}^{n}$ admits an action of $(\mathbf{C}^{\times})^{n+1}/\mathbf{C}^{\times}I$ by diagonal matrices modulo scalar matrices. When $n = 1$ this action is transitive (i.e., removing two points from the projective line leaves $\mathbf{C}^{\times}$), but in higher dimension the (intersections of) coordinate hyperplanes give additional orbits. That's not a proof of anything, but does indicate why the case $n = 1$ is special: Hyperplanes in $\mathbf{C}^{2}$ are lines, which project to points in $\mathbf{CP}^{1}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that circle action.  Note that having no fixed points is weaker than having a free action.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: The circle action is needed in order to use the slice theorem, however, as you correctly pointed out, the action here is not free, so I think the construction is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since all points on equivalent on $\mathbb{C}P^n$, WLOG, let $p = [1,0,0,\cdots]$. Then I claim $\mathbb{C}P^n-p$ homotopy retracts to $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$.

> To see this explicitly, define the homotopy to be
>   $$[a,b,c,\cdots]\mapsto [(1-t)a,b,c,\cdots].$$

or

> To see this abstractly, the projection $q:\mathbb{C}P^n-p\to \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ defined by
>   $$
> q:[a,b,c,\cdots]\mapsto [b,c,\cdots]
> $$
>   is a fibration with fiber $\mathbb{C}$ which is contractible. The LES of the fibration says that $q$ is a weak homotopy equivalence, by Whitehead's theorem this is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot understand to point you're trying to make with your answer. Could you please elaborate a little? Thank you.